# How to restore a project without project file

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, vb6, project

I am not a VB programmer but I have to deal with an older VB6 project.
From my idea there should be a VBP file, but this is not my case.
I only have frx, frm and bas file.
Being no expert I would therefore start with adding a project and add all files.
If I click on the MainFrm.frm that happens automatically:

[image]

Then I think I have to add the component that is the frx file but when I drag and drop it on the project I get this:

[image]

that therefore has not to be the right method.

Likewise if I try to start the project (just to see at what level it breaks, I get stuck even before starting:
[image]

and the log shows a long list of errors:

Line 139: Class MSFlexGridLib.MSFlexGrid of control grdH was not a loaded control class.

Line 329: Class MSFlexGridLib.MSFlexGrid of control grdMis was not a loaded control class.

Line 145: The property name _ExtentX in grdH is invalid.

Line 146: The property name _ExtentY in grdH is invalid.
...

Is therefore anything else that I can do?

Thanks

Patrick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right path.  However, you will only add the .frm and .bas files.  The .frx files are binary files taken care of by the IDE.  To resolve the errors, add References and Components as needed.  In the case of the MSFlexGrid, go to Project|Components and select the control from the list:

[image]

There will likely be more References and Components to add.  Keep working through them as the compiler brings them to your attention.  If you need to add a reference to a library there is a similar window under Project|References:

[image]

Comment: > The .frx files are binary files taken care of by the IDE.

*.frx files are used to store binary data, e.g. (form) icons or images used with that form and controls in that form. Some controls even store configuration data there, if properties aren't set at runtime (good practice), but rather only in the IDE. So missing *.frx files may cause some hassle. Patrick: make sure the *.frx files are located in the same folder as the respective *.frm.